# About binding a checkbox to string property in MVC viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my project I have a string field in the view model to display in a form and post back to the controller.

However for some reason, I'd like to display a checkbox, and retrieving string "True"/"False" from user input

I've searched through the internet and found this
[How to render a model property of string type as checkbox in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203583/how-to-render-a-model-property-of-string-type-as-checkbox-in-asp-net-mvc)
which leverage the editor template and achieve my need.

My question is that how do this be achieved, because in the editor template, I can only see it how to interpret the string to a checkbox, but it never explain or show how the checkbox value will be bind back to the string field with "True"/"False".

What should I do if I wanted "Yes"/"No" instead of "true"/"false", are there any converter that I need to make to parsing the checkbox to string?

Sorry for my bad English and lack of mvc knowledge, I just started MVC and web development for a few days.

UPDATE:
1. I am using ViewModel to bind with the forms, so I need something like Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.value)
while x.value is a string, obviously it is not possible with the default CheckboxFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking is how to save the value back into your database, which is more of a back-end C# or VB question.

As you know, when you submit a form on an HTML page, if a checkbox is ticked, it's value will be passed in the POST parameters back to the server:

front-end HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="theCheckBox" value="Yes" />
```

back-end C# in Page_Load() or similar

```
if(Request.Form["theCheckBox"] == "Yes") {
    // save value "Yes" into database
}
```

just remember that if the checkbox is NOT TICKED, Request.Form["theCheckBox"] will be null

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but since I am binding to a ViewModel, I'd like to have the value bind to the field with string property.

Comment: Sorry Matt, I've pasted a wrong link that I referenced before.
Take a look at this one, I'm using the answer in this thread, but I am not very understand what is happening behind the scene for binding.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203583/how-to-render-a-model-property-of-string-type-as-checkbox-in-asp-net-mvc